Mock MongoDB deleteMany implementation using Jest
Let's say I have a method called executeBackup15d() which takes no arguments. I'm testing different scenarios to force a failed execution. Inside that method, I have a condition that checks if the result of the deletion is not acknowledged, if is not, should throw an Error of failed deletion. I want to test that scenario using Jest.
I know in Jest you can overwrite functions using spyOn and mockImplementation, but the test gives me this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bsonOptions'). It is possible to test that scenario?
The important part of the function executeBackup15d:
const deleteResult = await sourceCollection.deleteMany(filter, getSessionObject());
if (deleteResult.acknowledged) logger_c.log('Documents deleted correctly');
else throw new Error('Delete not acknowledged. Failed deletion');

The test (the it part, I have defined the describe method as a parent):
it('Should throw a deletion error. Forced by mocking the mongoclient deletion method', async () => {
    // insert just one to avoid get not documents found error
    await collection.insertOne(generateFakeData(startDate, endDate));

    const throwDeleteError = jest.fn(() => { { acknowledged: false } });

    const originalDeleteMany = MongoClient.prototype.db().collection().deleteMany;

    jest.spyOn(MongoClient.prototype.db().collection(), 'deleteMany').mockImplementation(throwDeleteError);

    try {
        await executeBackup15d();
    } catch (err) {
        expect(err.message).toBe('Delete not acknowledged. Failed deletion');
    }

    // Restore the original deleteMany method
    jest.spyOn(MongoClient.prototype.db().collection(), 'deleteMany').mockImplementation(originalDeleteMany);
});

Error log:

● fifteen › generalTest › Should throw a deletion error. Forced by mocking the mongoclient deletion method

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bsonOptions')

      104 |             const throwDeleteError = jest.fn(() => { { acknowledged: false } });
      105 |
    > 106 |             const originalDeleteMany = MongoClient.prototype.db().collection().deleteMany;
          |                                                              ^
      107 |
      108 |             jest.spyOn(MongoClient.prototype.db().collection(), 'deleteMany').mockImplementation(throwDeleteError);
      109 |



Don't mock what you don't own. That's a very complex API, and reimplementing it as test doubles just means when that does change (e.g. you upgrade the MongoDB drivers) your tests continue to pass even though your code no longer works.

I see. Is there any other way I could implement a test that intentionally triggers a deletion error? I'm not trying to reimplement the behaviour of deletemany, I just want to deleteMany interionally returns acknowledged false in that specific test
